# using kinect to move cursor on macbook pro

Tags: macos

I need help. I have a kinect, and I would like to hook it to my laptop so that my right hand controls the mouse cursor. It's actually for a science fair project, and I don't want functionality for clicking or multitouch gestures, I just want cursor control. If anyone knows a good hack for this or a way to hack the kinect to do so (I have a good deal of free time, I wouldn't mind learning to hack kinect) please respond.

Answer (score 1):

[Kinect Jesture](https://github.com/hagino3000/KinectJesture) should let you do what you wanted:

> Control the mouse cursor and fire the key events (right or left).

Here is a [Vimeo video](https://vimeo.com/20846145) demonstrating Kinect Jesture.

Comment: And this will let me only use the mouse cursor? I don't want the swiping or clicking or showing all applications, just the moving the cursor. And only on the right hand.

Comment: Quick problem, I'm trying to compile Jesture in Xcode, but it comes up with errors about lines containing "DisposeGWorld" and "GetGWorldPixMap". What do I do? Sorry if I'm asking dumb questions, I'm an apple noob.